# Need to setup Connection Pooling properties for PostgreSQL in Maven project

Tags: postgresql, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, connection-pooling, aws-rds-data-service

My Application is serverless J2EE application and it is using AWS lambda for running. We have connection pool setup for Oracle in our application in which ojdbc driver and ucp for connection pool is being used, now we are migrating from Oracle to PostgreSQL. I don't know how to setup the properties of connection pool for PostgreSQL. Can anyone suggest me what are the dependencies I need to get and also how can I set connection pool for PostgreSQL. So please suggest me what to do.

Comment: Probably as simple as changing the driver class and connection url. Look at the properties you have for Oracle and think about which you'll need to change.

Comment: If your application is J2EE/JavaEE and uses the "traditional way of connecting to DB" for such an application, then you're using the connection pool of your application server, and nothing changes, except the `javax.sql.DataSource` or `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` or `javax.sql.XADataSource` instance your configure. Otherwise, you're not using the "traditional way" for J2EE applications, and you need to provide more information.